# Second display is detected, but doesn't work

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display

I've been having this issue for a couple of weeks now in Ubuntu 18.04.

My monitor is detected and can be configured in the displays settings, but the screen remains black and the windows disappear when I drag them there. Weirdly, I can move the cursor to that display, and see it moving around without any lag.

Playing around with the settings, I realized that if I change the Refresh Rate of the monitor and apply the changes, I can then see the desktop there (with whatever windows I had blindly moved there). However, I can't interact with it except for moving the cursor. If I drag a window there, it again moves, but remains unseen. If I change the refresh rate again, I will see that window, but again will be unable to interact with it. It's like I can see a picture of the state of the display whenever I change the refresh rate setting.

I've tried connecting the laptop to another monitor, and the same thing happens. 
The monitors work perfectly with windows laptops.

Comment: It may sound obvious, but have you tried rebooting after applying the changes? I had something similar some time ago on ubuntu 16.04 when I had to connect a 2nd monitor to a pc, and that monitor had vga port only (the other monitor had a DP). When connected separately and using only one monitor - both of them worked. After rebooting with only the vga monitor connected, and then connecting the DP monitor both of them worked. There was a problem syncing both monitors by the OS itself. Once it was done, the changes remained for good.